# How can I check in Android if a specific App is running and put a PIN Code on it?

Tags: java, android

I would like to check if a specific Android App is running. Then I want to ask the user for a PIN before he can use the App. Is this possible? How?

Comment: I cannot see how this would be possible as this would be a huge security problem if an external app could restrict you from using another app....Authentication should be done inside the opening app

Comment: Yes, but actually I have an application in wich this is possible and I want to build something like that to.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about compromising Android security without rationale.

Answer (score 0):

Other than rewriting a lot of core OS stuff, you would probably need to make your own Launcher to control the opening of apps.
This would let you control "desktop" launches as well as "app drawer" launches however you chose to. It's not a trivial thing to do however.

You would still have access through "recent apps" (again, unless you messed with the core OS) but if you ran from boot then the user couldn't get it into the history without traversing your checks. Returning to running apps would still be allowed this way though.

I don't think there's a BroadcastIntent to listen for an app's launch but [feel free to look through them](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) yourself.

At a minimum you'll need root access to block access to or force close if not allowed to launch launching apps.